# Why does RealityKit has such an high dirty memory footprint?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

Creating & loading a plain new AR project that contains only an ARView with no entity added results in about 330 MB of dirty memory(was checked using VM Tracker in instruments).

- This can be easily observed by adding the following line:

  ```
    arView.debugOptions = [.showStatistics]
  ```

It's really high and I'm wondering if others experienced this as well.
FYI, unity has a dirty memory of "only" 150 MB, which is also high.
SceneKit has a dirty memory of 80 MB.

Answer (score 2):

That's because all RealityKit's "hard core" options are ON by default. For lowering memory footprint you need to turn off "hard core" options and RealityKit app will be working considerably "smoother".

```swift
let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)

arView.renderOptions = [.disableMotionBlur,
                        .disableDepthOfField,
                        .disablePersonOcclusion,
                        .disableGroundingShadows,
                        .disableFaceOcclusions,
                        .disableHDR]
```

Comment: You're right, disabling all those options decreases the dirty memory to 91.5MB